# How can I migrate jsp-servlet to spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, spring-boot

I'm working on migrating a standard Servlet based (`web.xml`) application to spring-boot application.

We don't use spring-mvc, and web.xml configuration has more than 700 lines. I didn't find any solution for loading web.xml.

I tried to migrate all servlets/filters I have and faced problem with servlets without actually servlet class:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Neither `ServletRegistrationBean` nor `JspServlet` can be created from the file.

How can such Servlets be migrated assuming that I have other servlets mapped?

Comment: If you start using Spring MVC you can use your JSPs as the view of your application.

Answer (score 2):

Use a controller

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
        }

    }

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

in application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` class and use that in place of `web.xml`. You can map everything exactly to your needs through that.

This will be automatically be picked up by Spring Boot.

Comment: I've already done it, the question is how I can migrate serlvets without servlet class? it has only `jsp-file`